# How can I make a ternary condition in SpinalHDL?

Tags: fpga, spinalhdl

I would like to make a ternary condition in SpinalHDL as a ternary assignment in Verilog:

e.g.

```
wire my_condition = (this == that);

wire [1:0] my_ternary_wire = my_condition ? 2'b10 : 2'b01;
```

desired SpinalHDL code:

```scala
val myCondition = this === that

val myTernaryWire = myCondition ? B(3) : B(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just saw it is possible to use:

```scala
val myCondition = this === that

val myTernaryWire = myCondition ? B(3) | B(1)
```

just changing `:` to `|`